# In C, how do I only accept certain strings and continue to ask the user for input until valid input is entered?

Tags: c, input, while-loop

I am trying to write a simple program in C that takes in a string and performs an action based on that input. However, if the user inputs an invalid string, I want the program to ask the user for input again until the user supplies a valid input string.

Example output:

```
P: Please enter a string.
U: runMarathon
P: Unable to process request, please enter a valid Input:
U: rideBike
P: Unable to process request, please enter a valid Input:
U: sayHello
P: Hello World.
```

I had a program like this:

```
int num;

while (scanf("%d",&num) != 1 || num <= 0)
{
    printf("Please enter an integer greater than 0\n");
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

This program seemed to work; however I had an experienced C developer tell me never ever to use fflush(stdin).

Here is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    char input[];
    while (scanf("Please enter a command: %s\n",input))
    {
        printf("Your command is this: %s\n",input);
    }
}
```

However when running this method, after it accepts the input, the program will just continously print out:

```
Your command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: HelloYour command is this: Hello
```

and so forth.I was surprised that I could not find any resources for what seems like a simple problem. I understand that I can use strcmp to compare the strings, but how do I make the while loop wait for user input before it prints out the response again? Why can I not use fflush(stdin)?

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char input[50];
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a command:");
        if (scanf("%s", &input) != 1) //scanf returns the number of args successfully received
        {
            printf("Please enter a command\n");
        }

        printf("Please enter a valid command!\n");

    } while (strcmp(input, "good") != 0); //repeat above until input = "good"

                                          //print the good command
    printf("Your command is this: %s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

One little note, you should always make sure that your buffer into which you're writing is large enough to accommodate what is being put into it.

Comment: Do you even c? An array is not ever going to compare equal to a string literal.

Comment: @EOF I do C, but too much C# has me being rusty. :(

Comment: Tony, I ran the code. The while loop is missing a semi colon, and I used the strcmp instead of the !=. I still ran into the problem of the program infinitely printing out the first user input. Any ideas?

Comment: @EquityEcho I edited the code so it actually works now.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, thank you! It seems to work now! Why exactly was it running the infinite loop before? It seems like the ampersand was the fix.

Comment: @EquityEcho notice how I put the text printed in the `printf` before the `scanf` takes the input. `scanf` takes input, it doesn't do output.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with unexpected input is that `scanf` will not remove that input from the input buffer, so the next time the loop iterates it will try to read the same unexpected input.

The most common way to solve this is to read a whole line with e.g. `fgets`, and then use `sscanf` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why can I not use `fflush(stdin)`?

Technically you can do it but you MUST be very careful because `fflush` is defined by C standard only for output/update streams, not for input stream, therefore the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined*. What some implementations do then may be for example clearing of the input buffer. If you really have an urgent need to use this then consult your implementation's documentation and code.

---

C-99 Standard **§** 7.19.5.2/2/3 *The fflush function*

> Synopsis
>
> 1
>   `#include <stdio.h> 
>   int fflush(FILE *stream);`
>
> 2 If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which
>   the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes
>   any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host
>   environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> 3 If stream is a null pointer, the fflush function performs
>   this flushing action on all streams for which the behavior is defined
>   above.
>
> Returns
>
> 4 The fflush function sets the error indicator for the stream
>   and returns EOF if a write error occurs, otherwise it returns zero.